# How to model change of a dependent variable over time in a mixed model

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

It's a between-subject repeated measures model.
My hypothesis is that in both control & Treatment the dependent variable decreases over time.
How to model change of a dependent variable over time in a mixed model
I have tried fitting 5 models.

```
pupil.model1=lmer (change_in_pupil_size ~ Condition + Trial + (1|SubNum),data= dilation)
summary(pupil.model1)

pupil.model2=lmer (change_in_pupil_size ~ Condition + (1|SubNum),data= dilation)
summary(pupil.model2)

pupil.model3=lmer (change_in_pupil_size ~ Trial + (1|SubNum),data= dilation)
summary(pupil.model3)

pupil.model4=lmer(change_in_pupil_size ~ Condition*Trial + (1|SubNum),data= dilation)
summary(pupil.model4)

pupil.model5=lmer(change_in_pupil_size ~ Condition*Trial+ Condition+ Trial+(1|SubNum),data= dilation)
summary(pupil.model5)
```

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: change_in_pupil_size ~ Condition * Trial + (1 | SubNum)
   Data: dilation

REML criterion at convergence: -6251.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.0102 -0.4379 -0.0196  0.3957  9.5643 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 SubNum   (Intercept) 0.002075 0.04555 
 Residual             0.006931 0.08326 
Number of obs: 3008, groups:  SubNum, 38

Fixed effects:
                               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                   1.0558653  0.0107391  98.320
ConditionNonConfidence       -0.0030865  0.0160878  -0.192
Trial                        -0.0002920  0.0000704  -4.147
ConditionNonConfidence:Trial  0.0002071  0.0001059   1.955

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) CndtNC Trial 
CndtnNnCnfd -0.668              
Trial       -0.328  0.219       
CndtnNnCn:T  0.218 -0.332 -0.665
```

What is a right approach for doing this hypothesis test? I have attached output from one of my models.

Comment: *How to model change of a dependent variable over time in a mixed model* would be a good statistical question. However, as the question stands now, it really looks like a question concerned primarily with software implementation, which unfortunately is off-topic here. If you want to change your question to focus more on the statistical aspect, you can use the edit button below it.

Comment: @FransRodenburg done